# Saving and loading Python dict with savemat results in error

Tags: python, scipy, mat-file

Here is an minimal example of the error I get. If I understood the documentation correctly, this should be working, but it seems I did not.

```
a={}
a['test1']=1
a['test2']=2
a['test3']=3
import scipy.io as io
io.savemat('temp',{'a':a})
b = io.loadmat('temp')
b['a'].keys()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to be operating under the assumption that `scipy.io.savemat` is intended to be able to save a standard dictionary. I don't believe that is the case. The dictionary argument holds the names of *numpy arrays* which are written out into the Matlab file. So you can do something like this

```
import scipy.io as io
import numpy as np

y1=np.array([1,2,3,4])
y2=np.array([10,20,30,40])
y3=np.array([100,200,300,400])

a={}
a['test1']=y1
a['test2']=y2
a['test3']=y3
io.savemat('temp',a)
b = io.loadmat('temp')

print b['test1']
print b['test2']
print b['test3']
```

which gives:

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]]
[[10]
 [20]
 [30]
 [40]]
[[100]
 [200]
 [300]
 [400]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like loadmat returns [recarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html) instead of dict.
I checked with scipy 0.9.0.
Equivalent of `b['a'].keys()` will be `b['a'].dtype.names`.

Examples:

```
In [12]: b['a'].shape
Out[13]: (1, 1)

In [14]: b['a'].dtype.names
Out[16]: ('test1', 'test3', 'test2')

In [17]: b['a']['test1']
Out[17]: array([[[[1]]]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This seems not to be working for me: `b['a'].dtype.names` returns nothing and `b['a']['test1']` returns `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<input>", line 1, in <module> ValueError: field named test1 not found.`