# numpy.savez strips leading slash from keys

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to save a bunch of numpy arrays keyed by the absolute file path that the data came from using savez. However, when I use load to retrieve that data the leading slashes have been removed from the keys.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = {}
>>> data['/foo/bar'] = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> data.keys()
['/foo/bar']
>>> np.savez('/tmp/test', **data)
>>> data2 = np.load('/tmp/test.npz')
>>> data2.keys()
['foo/bar']
```

Is this behavior expected from numpy.savez? Is there a workaround or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: An `npz` file is a `zip` archive. Keys are archive file names. Look at the archive with a system tool. It may be sanitizing your names to fit that role.

Comment: yep, seems like this is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258069/numpy-savez-interprets-my-keys-as-filenames-ioerror

Comment: Who has a `/foo` root directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the stripping is done by the Python `zipfile` module, possibly on extract rather than on writing:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html

> Note If a member filename is an absolute path, a drive/UNC sharepoint and leading (back)slashes will be stripped, e.g.: ///foo/bar becomes foo/bar on Unix, and C:\foo\bar becomes foo\bar on Windows. And all ".." components in a member filename will be removed, e.g.: ../../foo../../ba..r becomes foo../ba..r. On Windows illegal characters (:, <, >, |, ", ?, and *) replaced by underscore (_).

Writing is done in `np.lib.npyio._savez`, first to a `tmpfile` and then to the archive with `zipf.write(tmpfile, arcname=fname)`.

```
In [98]: np.savez('test.npz',**{'/foo/bar':arr})
In [99]: !unzip -lv test.npz
Archive:  test.npz
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
     152  Stored      152   0% 2017-05-24 19:58 ef792502  foo/bar.npy
--------          -------  ---                            -------
     152              152   0%                            1 file
```

Comment: Thanks this answers it. I found the answer here to use base64 encode/decode gives me a reasonable workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258069/numpy-savez-interprets-my-keys-as-filenames-ioerror